# Correct way to upload file and store URL in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

This is my first day using Rails and even my first day programming with Ruby so I am unsure about a lot of the practises that the Ruby community uses.

I am trying to make this file upload and store the given file in a folder and have the path to that file stored in the database. What I have is working perfectly fine but I'm not sure if I am hitting some big no-nos or not.

The line I am most concerned about is where I do this:

```
params[:config][:url] = File.join("public/data/configs", params[:config][:file].original_filename)
```

Here is the full code of the create method:

```
params[:config][:url] = File.join("public/data/configs", params[:config][:file].original_filename)

    @map = Map.find(params[:map_id])
    @config = @map.map_config.new(map_config_params)

    if @config.valid?
        File.open(params[:config][:url], "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:config][:file].read) }
        @config.save
        redirect_to map_path(@map)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
```

And the `map_config_params` method:

```
private
    def map_config_params
        params.require(:config).permit(:name, :url)
    end
```

Comment: If you're going to use `"public/data/configs"`, there's little reason to use `File.join`, which is useful to automatically supply the path delimiters for a particular OS. As is, your code could end up returning a very confusing path consisting of forward and backward slashes if it ran on Windows. Ruby is smart enough to know that a pathname of all forward slashes needs to be converted on Windows, so it'd be OK to simply `join('/')` an array consisting of the values or simply interpolate the string and variable.

Comment: Instead of using `open`, `write` and `read` to copy a file, why not use [`FileUtils.cp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp)? And, you might consider the problem of accumulating files in the drop directory. Maybe `FileUtils.mv` would be better?

Comment: @theTinMan "public/data/configs" was just temporary while I was getting it working, but thank you for the advice, I will read into it more.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use carrier wave or paperclip for uploading files. Below are links to the gems

1. [Carrier Wave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)
2. [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)